# GPG error: https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

When I update, I get this error:

```
sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Hit:3 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                         
Hit:4 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                  
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:6 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:7 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease                         
Hit:9 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_19.x kinetic InRelease                   
Get:10 https://zotero.retorque.re/file/apt-package-archive ./ InRelease [2.153 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease [90,7 kB]      
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/transmission/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Get:13 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease [3.609 B]          
Get:2 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease [3.609 B]
Err:13 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease 
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C2850B265AC085BD riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>
Hit:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease
Err:2 https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C2850B265AC085BD riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease [90,7 kB]
Reading package lists... Done        
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C2850B265AC085BD riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>
W: GPG error: https://packages.element.io/debian default InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C2850B265AC085BD riot.im packages <packages@riot.im>
E: The repository 'https://packages.riot.im/debian default InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Yes I can, I will edit the post. Thanks

Comment: Your sources are a mess. Several are incompatible. For example, you have sources for `lunar` and `xenial`. These should not coexist on the same system. I suggest that you delete *all* of the sources that didn't come with your release. Then run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`. Never add sources that are for another release. Avoid adding sources unless necessary, and even then, take great care that they are actually compatible. Don't add sources for software that's already available in your repos. Adding sources fundamentally changes your system. It's not something to do haphazardly.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your kindness.

I'm completely new to this universe. Not knowing very well what I can or cannot.
Thank you again. I will follow your advice. Have a great day.

Comment: It's a common mistake that people make when they are not familiar with how software is all interrelated in Linux systems. Some of these apps are in official repositories, or they are available as snaps, so you don't need to add sources for a lot of these.